# Different node / entity templates based on display type

Tags: 7, theming

Is it possible to have different template files for different display modes of the same entity without using [template_preprocess_page()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7)? If not, how can I get all the available display modes for a certain entity type so I can create some sort of automatic template suggestion?

Eg: For a node I have by default the 'Full' and 'Teaser' display types. I can add more display types using [Display suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds) module or by creating a custom module. I need to create multiple template files like `node--content-type--teaser.tpl.php` to keep everything clean and not use lots of IF statements.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll go with this solution after all:

```
function MYMODULE_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'node__' . $vars['type'] . '__' . $vars['view_mode'];
}
```

Comment: Honestly that's the quickest and I think best way to go.  I've been doing that for a bunch of different sites and I can't think of a reason not to do it this way.

Comment: To then override use a name like: `node--article--teaser.tpl.php`

Comment: Just to add, 
I had to flush the cache twice in order to get this

Comment: Note that the [Entity Views Mode](https://drupal.org/project/entity_view_mode) module adds this for you.